# How to get path of selected files in a folder using python?

Tags: python, glob

I am using `glob` to retrieve the path of all files in a folder ("data"):

```
import glob
import geopandas

for file in glob.glob(r"/home/data/*.txt"):
    sf = geopandas.read_file(file)
```

However, here, I am interested in knowing how to retrieve only selected files whose names are listed in a variable as a list. For instance, I want the path of only the following files: aaa.txt, bdf.txt, hgr.txt, in the "data" folder, which are listed in variable "imp".

`imp = ['aaa.txt', 'bdf.txt', 'hgr.txt']`

Comment: so you are basically looking for `r"/home/data/aaa.txt"`, `r"/home/data/bdf.txt"` and `r"/home/data/hgr.txt"`? If yes, why you need the `glob` then?

Comment: Actually, there are hundreds of such files of interest, not just three, that have to be chosen from thousands of files in a folder.

Comment: Ok then you are looking for files like `aaa.txt`? Is it like `*aaa.txt` or `*aaa*.txt`?

Comment: Files' name does not follow any pattern. Instead, I want to read the path of all files whose names are available as a list stored in a variable "imp".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this could do it. Just loop through the files you need.

```py
import geopandas

imp = ['aaa.txt', 'bdf.txt', 'hgr.txt']
for file in imp:
    sf = geopandas.read_file(f'/home/data/{file}')
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot edit the answer since it's smaller then 6 characters. Your quote sign is in wrong place. `f"/home/data/"{file}`

Comment: @MSH I was able to fix it.

Comment: Ah sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
import geopandas

path = "/home/data/"
imp = [ 'aaa.txt', 'bdf.txt', 'hgr.txt']
for file in imp:
    if os.path.exists(path+file):
        sf = geopandas.read_file(path+file)
```